# ES6 export array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to export an array of objects in Javascript ES6:

settings.js

```
const elements = [
  {
    input: document.getElementById("name"),
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    type: "alpha"
  },
  {
    input: document.getElementById("addr1"),
    required: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    type: "alphanumeric"
  }
];

export default elements;
```

validation.js

```
import elements from "./settings.js";
```

I always get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<div id="form">
    <form action="">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name..">
        <div class="error"></div>

        <label for="addr">Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" id="addr1" name="addr1" placeholder="Your first address..">
        <div class="error"></div>

        <label for="addr1">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" id="addr2" name="addr2" placeholder="Your second address..">
        <div class="error"></div>

        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Your city..">
        <div class="error"></div>

        <label for="state">State</label>
        <select id="state" name="state">
            <option value="australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
        <div class="error"></div>

        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Your zip code..">
        <div class="error"></div>

        <input type="button" id="confirm" value="Ok">
        <input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="./validation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cannot figure out the reason!

Comment: Are you using babel?

Comment: no @ArupRakshit . . .

Comment: your import depends on the page element?  I'm not sure you can guarantee that your page elements are loaded (and have the right context) to be able to do the `document.getElementById()` there.  Do you get the problem if you change that to a literal string or a number?

Comment: `import` is synchronous, so it won't work in a web browser unless you compile it to code that a browser can actually understand. It should work if you put your code in a [module](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) however.

Comment: How are you loading the JS file? Please include the full error with location information if possible.

Comment: @loganfsmyth error is in import elements from "./settings";

Comment: I don't see that error here https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uvre2b?embed=1&file=index.js The values for `name` and `addr1` are not properly set though.

Comment: How are you importing the file? Are you loading it via Webpack, or via `<script>`? If `<script>` are you setting `type="module"`?

Comment: I am not importing in html the file that export the module. Should I? I just import in html the main js file that import the exported module.

Comment: Please add full examples of how you are importing into your question.

Comment: updated @loganfsmyth

Comment: I believe is related to the script src in html

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing this with?